# image_scale_and_crop

Tags: 7, media

In Drupal 6 there is a parameter $destination for the function 'image_scale_and_crop()' . The parameter is not available in D7. I have the following code block.

```
image_scale_and_crop($image, 100, 70);
```

This code is executed an the thumbnail is created in a path if I examine the file directory.

My question is, how I can determine the path where the cropped file is created in order to save it to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanksfully I could find the answer. After using this function,, I have to say drupal..

```
image_save($image);
```

It was due to insufficient information in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's better to use an [image style](http://admin/config/media/image-styles) and use [theme_image_style($variables)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

Comment: I agree. See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/17179/226.

Comment: I agree with you that it is possible to create an image style and use it. But in my case, I have to use the re-sizing, explicitly from the image_style because image size will be taken from database according to user assigned values.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the link to answer your question http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--image.inc/function/image_save/7